# XPCOM stub files

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xpcom

1- Is there any [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference) stub files (javascript) that can be used by PHPStorm for code completion?

2- Is there any way to facilitate FireFox plugin development in PHPStorm?

3- How can I set FireFox as the only browser target for syntax checking? Currently `for each()` construct is displayed as a syntax error but it is correct in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your JavaScript version in `preferences\JavaScript` to 1.7 or above to use `let` and `for each`.